# How to get x amount of characters from text file using php?

Tags: php, string, text, file-get-contents, substr

I'm trying to get about 200 letters/chars (including spaces) from a external text file. I've got the code to display the text i'll include that but to get certain letters i've got no idea. Once again i'm not talking about line's i really mean letters.

```
<?php
    $file = "Nieuws/NieuwsTest.txt";
    echo file_get_contents($file) . '<br /><br />';
?>
```

Comment: you can use `substr` function in PHP.

Comment: You want to get first 200 character of string?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the fifth parameter of `file_get_contents`:

```
$s = file_get_contents('file', false, null, 0, 200);
```

This will work only with 256-character set, and will *not* work correctly with multi-byte characters, since PHP [does not offer native Unicode support](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.details), unfortunately.

## Unicode

In order to read specific number of *Unicode* characters, you will need to implement your own function using PHP extensions such as [intl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php) and [mbstring](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php). For example, a version of [`fread`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php) accepting the maximum number of UTF-8 characters can be implemented as follows:

```
function utf8_fread($handle, $length = null) {
  if ($length > 0) {
    $string = fread($handle, $length * 4);
    return $string ? mb_substr($string, 0, $length) : false;
  }

  return fread($handle);
}
```

If `$length` is positive, the function reads the maximum number of bytes that a UTF-8 string of that number of characters can take (a UTF-8 character is represented as 1 to 4 8-bit bytes), and extracts the first `$length` multi-byte characters using [`mb_substr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php). Otherwise, the function reads the entire file.

A UTF-8 version of `file_get_contents` can be implemented in similar manner:

```
function utf8_file_get_contents(...$args) {
  if (!empty($args[4])) {
    $maxlen = $args[4];
    $args[4] *= 4;
    $string = call_user_func_array('file_get_contents', $args);
    return $string ? mb_substr($string, 0, $maxlen) : false;
  }

  return call_user_func_array('file_get_contents', $args);
}
```

Comment: That's the best method if he dont need to store the full text in a var ! Nice ! Simpliest solutions are always the best

Comment: One question though, is it multy-byte safe like mb_substr ? http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php#90581

Comment: @Math, `file_get_contents` is binary-safe. However, the limit means the number of bytes, but not Unicode characters for instance. So for non-ASCII characters he will need another solution.

Answer (score 1):

You should use substr() functions.

But i recommend you to use the multy byte safe [mb_substr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php).

```
    $text = mb_substr( file_get_contents($file), 200 ) . '<br /><br />';
```

With substr you will get trouble if there is some accents etc. Thoses problems will not happen with mb_substr()

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
<?php
    $file = "Nieuws/NieuwsTest.txt";
    echo substr( file_get_contents($file), 0, 200 ) . '<br /><br />';
?>
```